# React native - Webview video reload itself on parent state change

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, webview

I have the following structure:

```
class Parent extends Component { 
    state = { isHeaderCollapsed : false }

    render() { 
        <ScrollView decelerationRate="fast" stickyHeaderIndices={isHeaderCollapsed && [0]} scrollEventThrottle={1} onScroll={(value) => this.setState({isHeaderCollpased: true})} style={styles.body}>
            <JobHeader collapsed={isHeaderCollapsed} />
            <WebView allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true} style={[styles.video, style]} javaScriptEnabled={true} source={{uri: mediaUrl}} />
       </ScrollView>
     }
```

On iOS , very time I change the state of the parent component, the youtube video in the webview refreshes itself. I don't want this to happen.
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to check if you need rerender or not:

```
class Parent extends Component { 
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            isHeaderCollapsed : false
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        return nextState.isHeaderCollapsed !== this.state.isHeaderCollapsed;
    }

    render() { 
        <ScrollView decelerationRate="fast" stickyHeaderIndices={isHeaderCollapsed && [0]} scrollEventThrottle={1} onScroll={(value) => this.setState({isHeaderCollpased: true})} style={styles.body}>

                <JobHeader collapsed={isHeaderCollapsed} />
                <WebView allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true} style={[styles.video, style]} javaScriptEnabled={true} source={{uri: mediaUrl}} />

       </ScrollView>
     }
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, Already tried that. I think that this: 
````stickyHeaderIndices={isHeaderCollapsed && [0]}```` method which causes a sticky header makes the entire children to re render again

Comment: Try moving WebView into a custom component.  Then you can block it from rerendering with shouldComponentUpdate when the parent updates.